# UIBarButtonSystemItem Info and Statistics

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need two buttons that I can't find: Info button and Stats button for UINavigationBar. Is there a way to find buttons that represent similar things without painting them?

Comment: there is no such default button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps you:

```
 //for info button using custom UIButton
  UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

For Statistics no such default button is available

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 / 4

```
let infoButton = UIButton(type: .infoDark)
infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(navbarButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoButton))
```